# How do I map us-states just by names? In R

Tags: r, dictionary, dplyr, usmap

In R I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
head(map)

mapstates mapdelay 
1    Alabama      457        
2     Alaska      374       
3    Arizona     2852       
4   Arkansas      339        
5 California    11609       
6   Colorado     3298
```

I would like to plot the frequencies on a map.

Searching the www i have found the usmap package f.e. . But all the solutions that I have found require lattitude and longitude data which I do not have.

Using the usmap package and dplyr I tried connecting
lattitude and longitude data from usmap to my dataframe:

```
library(dplyr)

newdata<- left_join(mapstates, delaymap, by= "state")
```

and this error message popped up:

"Fehler: `by` can't contain join column `state` which is missing from LHS
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred."

Is there any way to plot my data just with the name of the states?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your `data.frame` “map” doesn’t have a column named “states”
and therefore the join command is failing. I can’t test this, since I don’t
have the exact datasets you are using, but it might just work,
to change your command as follows:

```r
newdata <- left_join(mapstates, delaymap, by= c("mapstates" = "state"))
```

I executed the following code, to reproduce your idea in my environment and
it does work. I am using the “statepop” `data.frame` from the `usmap`
package to join your data to, as it has the `fips` code needed by the
package, to identify states (or counties). Also see the documentation on
the `data` argument of `?plot_usmap()`.

```r
library(dplyr)
library(usmap)
library(ggplot2)

map_df <- tibble::tribble(
      ~"mapstates",~"mapdelay",
  "Alabama"  ,   457,
  "Alaska"  ,   374,
  "Arizona"  ,  2852,
  "Arkansas"  ,   339,
  "California"  , 11609,
  "Colorado"  ,  3298
  )

new_df <- left_join(statepop, map_df, by = c("full" = "mapstates"))

plot_usmap(data = new_df, values = "mapdelay", color = "white") + 
  scale_fill_continuous(
    low = "white", high = "red", name = "Delay", label = scales::comma
  ) + theme(legend.position = "right")
```

[image]

Note: Some of the states are not colored, because I do not have your full dataset.